# Invalid write of size 8 on calloc of double array

Tags: c++, valgrind, calloc

I didn't want to ask it here but I'm pretty much out of options.

I have a Matrix structure

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct Matrix{
  double *mat;
  int rows;
  int columns;
} Matrix;
```

that I initialize like this

```
Matrix* init_Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
  Matrix *matrix = (Matrix*) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));

  matrix->rows = rows;
  matrix->columns = columns;
  matrix->mat = (double*) calloc(rows*columns, sizeof(double));

  return matrix;
}
```

However, when I ran it as part of a larger code, it ended up giving

```
malloc(): corrupted top size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The error is not systematic and happens at the second initialisation in the code. This prompted me to test it with `valgrind` which gave the following output

```
==19211== Invalid write of size 8
==19211==    at 0x1096DF: odometer(Robot*, double, double, double) (main.cc:41)
==19211==    by 0x109B6F: main (main.cc:82)
==19211==  Address 0x4dcbe68 is 0 bytes after a block of size 72 alloc'd
==19211==    at 0x483CD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19211==    by 0x109C33: init_Matrix(int, int) (matrix_gr7.cc:18)
==19211==    by 0x1095BD: odometer(Robot*, double, double, double) (main.cc:38)
==19211==    by 0x109B6F: main (main.cc:82)
```

The `calloc` is evidently the problem but I can't find what I did wrong. Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT: Adding additional code for error reproduction
`matrix_gr7.h`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct Matrix{
  double *mat;
  int rows;
  int columns;
} Matrix;

Matrix* init_Matrix(int rows, int columns);
void free_Matrix(Matrix *matrix);

Matrix* matrix_product(Matrix *a, Matrix *b);

Matrix* matrix_sum(Matrix *a, Matrix *b);

Matrix* matrix_transpose(Matrix *a);

void print_matrix(Matrix *a);
```

`matrix_gr7.cc`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "matrix_gr7.h"


Matrix* init_Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
  Matrix *matrix = (Matrix*) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));

  matrix->rows = rows;
  matrix->columns = columns;
  matrix->mat = new double[rows*columns];

  return matrix;
}

void free_Matrix(Matrix *matrix) {
  if (matrix != NULL) {
    if (matrix->mat != NULL) {
      free(matrix->mat);
    }
    free(matrix);
  }
}

Matrix* matrix_product(Matrix *a, Matrix *b) {
  Matrix *c = init_Matrix(a->rows, b->columns);

  double temp;

  for (int i = 0; i < a->rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < b->columns; j++) {
      temp = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < a->columns; k++) {
        temp += (a->mat[k+(i*a->columns)])*(b->mat[j+(k*b->columns)]);
      }
      c->mat[i*(c->columns) + j] = temp;
    }
  }
  return c;
}

Matrix* matrix_sum(Matrix *a, Matrix *b) {
  Matrix *c = init_Matrix(a->rows, a->columns);
  for (int i = 0; i < a->rows*a->columns; i++) {
    c->mat[i] = a->mat[i] + b->mat[i];
  }
  return c;
}

Matrix* matrix_transpose(Matrix *m) {
  Matrix *n = init_Matrix(m->columns, m->rows);
  for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
      n->mat[i + j*n->columns] = m->mat[j + i*m->columns];
    }
  }
  return n;
}

void print_matrix(Matrix* m) {
  for (int i = 0; i < m->rows*m->columns; i++) {
    printf("%f  ,", m->mat[i]);
    if ((i+1)%m->columns  == 0) {
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

`robot.h`

```
#include "matrix_gr7.h"

typedef struct Robot {
  double x;
  double y;
  double th;
  Matrix *Sig_p;
  double last_t_update;
} Robot;

Robot* init_Robot(double x, double y, double th);

void free_Robot(Robot* robot);
```

`robot.cc`

```
#include "robot.h"
#include "matrix_gr7.h"

Robot* init_Robot(double x, double y, double th) {
  Robot* robot = (Robot*) malloc(sizeof(Robot));
  robot->x = x;
  robot->y = y;
  robot->th = th;
  robot->last_t_update = 0;
  robot->Sig_p = init_Matrix(3, 3);

  return robot;
}

void free_Robot(Robot* robot) {
  free_Matrix(robot->Sig_p);
  free(robot);
}
```

`main.cc`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "matrix_gr7.h"
#include "robot.h"

void odometer(Robot* cvs, double w_r, double w_l, double t) {
  Matrix *grad_p_f = init_Matrix(3, 3);
  grad_p_f->mat[7] = 0; grad_p_f->mat[8] = 0; grad_p_f->mat[9] = 1;

  Matrix *grad_p_f_T = matrix_transpose(grad_p_f);

  Matrix *grad_rl_f = init_Matrix(3, 2);
  grad_rl_f->mat[5] = 1.0/0.225;
  grad_rl_f->mat[6] = -1.0/0.225;

  Matrix *grad_rl_f_T = matrix_transpose(grad_rl_f);
  Matrix *Sig_rl = init_Matrix(2,2);

  Matrix *temp1 = matrix_product(grad_p_f, cvs->Sig_p);
  Matrix *temp2 = matrix_product(temp1, grad_p_f_T);
  Matrix *temp3 = matrix_product(grad_rl_f, Sig_rl);
  Matrix *temp4 = matrix_product(temp4, grad_rl_f_T);

  free_Matrix(cvs->Sig_p);
  cvs->Sig_p = matrix_sum(temp2, temp4);

  free_Matrix(grad_p_f); free_Matrix(grad_p_f_T); free_Matrix(Sig_rl);
  free_Matrix(grad_rl_f); free_Matrix(grad_rl_f_T);
  free_Matrix(temp1); free_Matrix(temp2);
  free_Matrix(temp3); free_Matrix(temp4);
  cvs->last_t_update = t;
}

int main() {
  Robot* robot = init_Robot(0, 0, 0);

  odometer(robot, 1, 1, 1);
  matrix_transpose(robot->Sig_p);

  free_Robot(robot);

  return 0;
}

The program fails at the `Matrix *grad_p_f_T = matrix_transpose(grad_p_f);` line but `valgrind` shows memory issues way before that.
```

Comment: What you did wrong is failing to read stackoverflow's [help]: the shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone on stackoverflow.com can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: `typedef struct` then `malloc()` and `calloc()` - this is not C++

Comment: Do **not** use `*alloc` family of functions in C++ until you really know what you are doing.  They don't actually create anything and need more handling (calling placement new on the returned pointer)

Comment: *However, when I ran it as part of a larger code,* -- Given the code you posted, any one here could write a simple 2 or 3 line program that causes trouble using your `Matrix`.

Comment: A [mcve] would be best. That's almost never "full code" in the sense of copy/pasting your real project here. It's the temporary project (that is a complete program, but does not contain some or most of the things you need in your real project) that you come up with by narrowing down the problem as much as possible!

Comment: Why do you initialize a matrix on the heap in `init_Matrix`? Use the constructor: https://wandbox.org/permlink/6W8lYKKHZX1Yecyg

Comment: You tagged this question with C++ but it looks like C. Are you sure you use a C++ compiler?

Comment: Look at the code in @ThomasSablik's link. Isn't it amazing that it does not have any `malloc/free` or even `new[]/delete[]`? Yet, that code is likely to actually work.

Comment: Some said it looks like C (and basically it is C) but uses g++ for compilation. The main reason is that it's part of a larger code that needs C++ exclusive features. I'm updating my post to add a reproducible example.

Comment: After `matrix->mat = new double[rows*columns];` you can't `free(matrix->mat)` `but uses g++ for compilation` No, it's either C or C++. If you use g++ then you compile it as C++ and then it's compiled C++. Then, if this is C++, the question arises, why do you not use c++ features that make life much easier? `grad_p_f->mat[7]` is out of bounds - after `init_Matrix(3, 3);` you have `3 * 3 = 6` doubles, so the last index is 5.... Use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`

Comment: I would advise to rewrite it in c++ with `std::vector` array allocations and `std::unique_ptr` for pointers and provide `Matrix::operator[]` overload that would throw an exception if the index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The write to `grad_p_f->mat[9] = 1;` shortly after allocating the array is out of bounds.  Your array is 3*3=9 elements, and indexing starts at 0 (so valid subscripts are 0..8 inclusive).

This write is past the end of the memory allocated by the `calloc` call, and is reported by valgrind.

I think all of your subscripts are off by one.